# Remove all characters after a position in a csv file

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV File that is delivered to me daily merged with data at the end I do not need like this:

```
    "Date","Site","PCode","PName","Sales"
    "2013/03/10 00:00:00","10195","66011","GT 1","9"
    "2013/03/10 00:00:00","22413","66005","GT 2E","4"
    "2013/03/10 00:00:00","10082","66003","GT 23E","6"
    "SCode"
    "12345678"
```

I would like to run a PHP script on it that removes all characters including and after the "SCode". The Position in the file and the total file length changes daily so it need to be from the word not from a set position.

Any Ideas? I have had a look but most examples remove after a set position that does not change with different file. Thank You.

New File like this:

```
    "Date","Site","PCode","PName","Sales"
    "2013/03/10 00:00:00","10195","66011","GT 1","9"
    "2013/03/10 00:00:00","22413","66005","GT 2E","4"
    "2013/03/10 00:00:00","10082","66003","GT 23E","6"
```

From Feedback Below have used this thanks:

```
    <?
    $path="test.csv";
    $csv = file_get_contents($path);

    $new_csv = strstr($csv,'"SCode"',true); //csv file up to "SCode"

    $file = fopen("test2.csv","w");
    fwrite($file,$new_csv);
    fclose($file);
    ?>
```

Comment: show some code you tried or are stuck at..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the csv file is not ridiculously big, you can use the `strstr()` function, with the flag for `$before_needle` set to true:

```
$csv; //your loaded in csv file as a string

$new_csv = strstr($csv,'"SCode"',true); //csv file up to "SCode"
```

Comment: <?
$path="test.csv";
$csv = file_get_contents($path);

$new_csv = strstr($csv,'"SCode"',true); //csv file up to "SCode"

$file = fopen("test2.csv","w");
fwrite($file,$new_csv);
fclose($file);
?>